# Is there a corpus I could use to support the answer I am giving?

Tags: discussion, answers

When answering a question about which phrase to use, I would like to be able to backup my answer with data taken from a [corpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus).

Is there any Esperanto corpus I could refer in my answers, and that is updated with sentences used nowadays? If there are more than one, what is the one I should prefer (for objective reasons)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[tekstaro.com](http://tekstaro.com/) is the only one that I'm aware of and it is used a lot on this SE. However it only uses a limited selection of books and as far as I know it's not updated regularily.

Comment: Another more extensive corpus is http://corp.hum.sdu.dk/cqp.eo.html. However, unlike tekstaro.com, it contains also texts that are written by people without a very good command of Esperanto, so it has to be used with a grain of salt.

Comment: @MarcosCramer Your comment answers my question too. Would you write it as answer?

Comment: @MarcosCramer I’ve made my answer a community wiki so if you want you could just add it directly to this answer. I won’t get points for the upvotes any more if I understand correctly

Comment: @NeilRoberts Users don't get any point from posts on meta sites. The reputation used on a meta site is the reputation on the main site.

Comment: I would rather leave suggestions separated. In this way, users can up-vote the one they think more appropriate. How can users vote if there is more than one suggestion per answer?

Answer (score 0):

The best ressource I have to know if something is used in actual, everyday, homo-to-homo Esperanto is the history from all Telegram groups in Esperanto. (More than 150 000 messages!) But there is a big problem: the content of these groups is not public, and newcomers can not see the whole history. You may give a good answer based on the frequency on Telegram, but you can not provide a checkable source easily.

Comment: I think the Lojban IRC has some kind of method of logging all of their chats into some kind of corpus specifically for this kind of thing. I wonder if we could find a way to take a page out of their book?

Comment: A corpus allows you to look for occurrences of words and group of words. Having to look into the messages of a group is not what I expect from a corpus.